# MySQL - Using SHA2 in WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sha256

thanks in advance! So here is my query

```
$query = "
        SELECT
            A.id
            U.email,
            SHA2(U.email, 256) AS sha
        FROM S.Action A
        LEFT JOIN S.Users U
            ON U.ID = A.id
        WHERE A.id = ". $id ."
        ";
```

Which works fine, and 'sha' has the expected value. However, what I want to do is add this WHERE condition in

```
AND SHA2(U.email, 256) = ". $pass ."
```

But as soon as that is entered, the query returns with nothing. When I dump out $pass and 'sha' after the query returns, without that WHERE condition, they match. But when I try to look at that match before everything is grabbed, it finds nothing. Is this something I cannot do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect in the first example, `$userid` is an integer and the column id is some type of INT  as well, so it's being cast to integer and working fine

The second where clause you're adding to query, the result of the SHA2 funciton is clearly not an integer but a string, so it should be in quotes:

```
   $query = "
       SELECT
        A.id
        U.email,
        SHA2(U.email, 256) AS sha
       FROM S.Action A
       LEFT JOIN S.Users U
        ON U.ID = A.id
        WHERE A.id = ". $id ." AND SHA2(U.email, 256) = '".$pass."'";
```

**Note that if this input is coming from user input, you'll want to use parameters and not concatenate the query together as is done above. This could open your site up to SQL injection attacks.**

Comment: Well that's embarrassing ha. Thank you

Comment: It's for unsubscribing people from an email. I sha256 their email, combine that  with their user ID in a string, then base64 encode that entire string, then it gets passed into the URL. Just wanted to obscure that information and provide some saftey field so that a user can't start typing IDs into the URL and unsubscribe people. I was testing with the SELECT, the actual will be a DELETE

Comment: @QuantumScripting I'd recommend not using insterting manually into the query for this, but use prepared statements instead.  If you're pulling `$pass` from a form submission (and `$id`) you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: $pass and $id only ever come from the email. These emails pass this information along, and I just pull that from them. The user never submits anything. However, with that said, I am unfamiliar with prepared statements so I will look into that. Thank you